# General bookmark for url link for Google docs

Tags: google-docs, links, bookmarks

I understand that you can insert a bookmark into Google docs and link to it with the url. Also if you have headings inside the document, each heading has it's own url.

**My question is:** is there a generic form of it?

For example. Let's say I have 50 documents, in each document, I will have a heading titled "questions". Currently the url is unique for each different doc for the heading "questions". Is there a way to have a generic formula for that heading and I could just swap out the file ID when generating a url link?

Answer (score 1):

Experiment shows the generation of bookmark Id does not follow any simple rule; Google may be using some [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for this purpose.

I created two bookmarks in one document, they got Ids
`id.bp1zcvxln5kg` and `id.f93qmv8z8g1s`. Then created a bookmark in another, it got Id `id.apnggattoj3a`. Beyond the initial `id.`, there is no pattern here.

If you need to generate URLs of bookmarks programmatically, a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) can help. For example, this function logs the URLs of all bookmarks in the active document.

```
function bookmarks() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var bookmarkUrls = doc.getBookmarks().map(function(bookmark) {
    return 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + docId + '/edit#bookmark=' + bookmark.getId();
  });
  Logger.log(bookmarkUrls);  
}
```